# Multiple edmx in one project

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have a project with one edmx file. Test class works correctly.when i add the edmx with a different name and namespace, but connect to a similar base structure ,After the addition, before acting classes stops working and I get the message:

```
 Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType
 (InvalidOperationException)
```

Once i delete the added edmx, the project is working properly.Is there a possibility of adding two edmx files to a single project, so as not to appear to be erroneous references to the metadata?

**Currently I use this connection string**:

```
<add name="MSSQLEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RiskEntityModel.csdl|res://*/RiskModelLibrary.Lib.RiskEntityModel.MSSQL.ssdl|res://*/RiskEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=_DBSERVERNAME_;User ID=_DBUSERNAME_;Password=_DBPASSWORD_;Initial Catalog=_DBPATH_;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to construct `EntityConnectionDescription` manually and pass it to your custom implementation of `ObjectContext`.

So basically instead of standard EF context-buildup functionality (which reads from app config) you create your own.

Comment: Not really sure if this will help. Post edited to bring what I want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, can't really understand your addendum.

Comment: But connectionString is correct. In the absence of one edmx file everything works fine. Why do I get a message that it can not download the schema from the metadata, if he's there?

Comment: My presumption is that it simply cannot decide which connection string/edmx to use. But I'm not sure I understand your problem anymore.

Comment: No. Depending on the selected database is suitable ConnectionString. However, the addition of a second edmx, if the application had not seen ssdl, csdl and msl files in the resources. It may be the changes the location?

Comment: And you want to have two models but use only one? I guess EF tries to create instances of both and finds connection string for only one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a workaround. I added a new project in which I created a model to MSSQL database. Generated ssdl file I copy to base project embedded resource, and then if you wish to use MSSQL database, loads located in the resource file ssdl. Everything works fine. But I wanted to avoid the creation of this additional project. So far I do not know how to do it, so this way it is about.