# Multiple .edmx in single Asp.Net MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, metadata, edmx

I am creating a website in ASP.Net MVC and I need to access 2 different databases.  I am currently using 2 .edmx files each with their own connection string in the web.config file.  I have one Metadata file that describes my different tables with the necessary attributes.  My issue is that in a controller I am trying to work with both db's, but I keep getting this error:

```
The entity type <object2Metadata> is not part of the model for the current context.
```

I have tried everything I can think of, such as using var and only specifically typing my objects when necessary and that error will just pop up at different steps in my code, no matter how hard I try to get it right.

What I'm trying to accomplish:  I have two tables in two different databases that I need to compare their e-mails and get all the e-mail accounts that are in one table but not in the other, and put those corresponding objects in a list.

I have created metadata in my project that maps these out into objects.  The objects aren't the same and can't be mapped out to equal each other as object2 has attributes in it that don't exist in object1 and there is no corresponding field, so I can't just convert object2 to object1 and do a compare.  I've tried just pulling out the emails from each object and putting them each in their own list and then comparing those and getting the differences that way.  This works, however then when I go to access the db2 again to pull out the objects that have those e-mails, I get that error again.  It seems I only get the error when I start trying to use that 2nd db.  I've checked my connection strings and they are correct.  It lets me pull out the initial objects from db2 in put them in var..so I know the connection string works, but it seems the error occurs when I try to manipulate data from db2...if that makes sense.

I've done my research and I can't find anything that answers my specific issue.
Such as: [Multiple edmx in one project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431455/multiple-edmx-in-one-project)   or  [How to create multiple edmx in same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690891/how-to-create-multiple-edmx-in-same-project).

Here are some code examples of what I've been doing:
Controller -

```
namespace project.Controllers
{
    public class myController: Controller
    {
      //both these statements compute just fine with no errors.
      private db1Entities db = new db1Entities();
      private db2Entities adb = new db2Entities ();

        // GET: Exchange
        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
          //Getting my initial lists from the db's
          //Both these statements compute with no errors as well
          var mbe = db.table1.AsEnumerable().ToList();
          var abe = adb.table2.AsEnumerable().ToList();

          //This list would be used for me to convert Obj2 into Obj1
          List<object1> abeConverted = new List<object1>();

          //This list would then hold the items in List<obj2> that aren't
          //in List<obj1>
          List<object1> abeDiff = new List<object1>();

         ////Here's where I was going to try to just filter by email
         //List<string> mbeEmails = new List<string>();
         //List<string> abeEmails = new List<string>();            

        //Here is where I actually converted obj2 into obj1-no error here
        foreach (object2 a in abe)
        {
            object1 m = new object1 ();
            m.pk_email = a.mail;

            if (a.secureMail.Equals('F'))
                m.isSecure = false;
            else
                m.isSecure = true;

            m.jobCode = null;
            m.workOrder = null;
            m.isDisabled = false;
            m.isNonBillable = false;
            m.createdDate = a.createdDate;

            abeConverted.Add(m);
        }

        //Here's where I would have extracted emails to lists from obj's
        //foreach (var m in mbe)
        //{
        //    string e = "";
        //    e = m.pk_email;
        //    mbeEmails.Add(e);
        //}

        //foreach (var a in abe)
        //{
        //    string e = "";
        //    e = a.mail;
        //    abeEmails.Add(e);
        //}

         ////Email lists compare to get differences             
        //List<string> diffEmails = (from a in abeEmails
        //                    join m in mbeEmails on a equals m into d
        //                    from od in d.DefaultIfEmpty()
        //                    where od == null
        //                    select a).ToList<string>();

        //compare to get differecnes by objects after the obj2 convert
        //Here is where the error pops up by using this approach.
        abeDiff = (from a in abeConverted
                   join m in mbe on a.pk_email equals m.pk_email into d
                   from od in d.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where od == null
                   select a).ToList();

        //This would be used if needed to get the objects after the email
        //compare.  Here is where the error pops up using this filtered 
        //emails approach.
        //foreach (string e in diffEmails)
        //{
        //    object2 a = new object2 ();
        //    a = abe.Where(b => b.mail == e).FirstOrDefault();
        //    abeDiff.Add(a);
        //}

        //Turning my list into a pagedList object for the view
        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        var abePage = abeDiff.OrderBy(a => 
             a.pk_email).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

        ViewBag.abePage = abePage;
        return View(abeDiff.OrderBy(a => 
             a.pk_email).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

        }
    }
}  //end Controller
```

Here's my MetaData for the two objects -

```
namespace project.Models
{
  public class Metadata
  {
  }

  public class object1Metadata
  {
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Required]
    public string pk_email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Job Code")]
    [Required]
    public string jobCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Work Order")]
    [Required]
    public string workOrder { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Secure?")]
    [Required]
    public bool isSecure { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Disabled?")]
    public bool isDisabled { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Non-Billable?")]
    [Required]
    public bool isNonBillable { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
  }

  public class object2Metadata
  {
    //[Display(Name = "ID")]
    //public double Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department Number")]
    public string departmentNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Division")]
    public string division { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Agency")]
    public string agency { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
    public string departmentName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string mail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Size")]
    public string mbSize { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Distinguished Name")]
    public string distinguishedName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Instant Messaging")]
    public string instantMessaging { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Secure Mail")]
    public string secureMail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Account Type")]
    public string typeOfAccount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Extract Date")]
    public DateTime extractDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created Date")]
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

Sorry for the lengthy question, since I'm not sure the exact issue I wanted to describe exactly what I'm doing and how.  I have lots of code commented out in my controller, just showing you the different things I have tried.

If something's not clear, I can answer any questions or better describe something.

UPDATE: Connection Strings
--To protect myself from posting private data I did a search and find and replaced the connection names with db1 and db2 and the server name to myServer.
I made sure that the name was typed exactly on all occurrences and that the server name was correct...so those two things won't be the issue.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="db1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.db1.csdl|res://*/Models.db1.ssdl|res://*/Models.db1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myServer;initial catalog=db1;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   <add name="db2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.db2.csdl|res://*/Models.db2.ssdl|res://*/Models.db2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myServer;initial catalog=db2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

We use partial classes of Metadata type for our entity classes...as follows:

```
namespace project.Models
{
  public class PartialClasses
  {
  }

  [MetadataType(typeof(object1Metadata))]
  public partial class object1
  { }

  [MetadataType(typeof(object2Metadata))]
  public partial class object2
  { }

}
```

Comment: This error is more likely because of bad connection strings. Could you post your connection string?

Comment: I updated my question to include connectionStrings as requested by @NagarajRaveendran

Comment: Connection strings look good!

Comment: The exception is about `object2Metadata`. So I'd start looking at where this class is used. I'm pretty sure you have a property of this type (object2Metadata) in one of your entity classes.

Comment: @GertArnold The controller is the first place I've tried referencing the object2 class and we define our entity classes as partial classes from the metadata.  I do see your point though.  The error specifically references my object2Metadata.   It's Friday and it'll probably hit me as I spend my weekend thinking about this constantly. lol.  I feel like there has to be something I'm missing right in front of me.  Thanks for your help.  I posted the PartialClasses to the end of my question.

Comment: using `var` doesn't mean you are not typing your objects. it's just a shortcut, but the compiler will use the right type at compile time, inferred from the type you assign to the variable.

Comment: it looks like somewhere in your code you are accidentally using `object2Metadata` with your DbContext. since the metadata is not part of the model, EF complains about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added or changed any of the schema? If so, the simplest option is to delete both EDMX's and create them again

Comment: hardly the simplest, and most likely won't solve the problem, because once he creates them again, he will hit the same issue. EDMX files often include many customizations that will need to be recreated.